# Ngrx/effects is not working in async with angular 2

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity, angular-ngrx-data

Am new to Ngrx, We got stuck with the implementation , Need some help

Architecture:
We are trying to fill the store when the User is authenticated by that time am trying to redirect.

Expectation:
Effects should be called as async and In ui we have to do the redirect

Problem:
Redirection to Homepage is happening only after the ngrx/effect api call is done.

```
 this.userService.authenticateUser(this.userId.toUpperCase(), this.password, (user) => {
            this.authenticatedUser = user;                
            //Call the ngrx dispatchMethod to fill the store
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/home");
             this.ngrxGetModule_data();

 async  ngrxGetModule_data() {
        this.store.dispatch({ type: Affaire_Action.Affaire_Addstore_Login });
        //this.store.dispatch({ type: Affaire_Action.Initial_Store });
    }



@Effect()
    updateAffaireStore$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(Affaire_Action.Affaire_Addstore_Login)
        .map<Action, string>(toPayload)
        .switchMap(res => this.affaireService.getAffairesSearchSuggetions('')
            //.delay(10000)
            .map(res => (
                {
                    type: Affaire_Action.Affaire_on_Success, payload: ({ "parameter": SearchSuggestion, "data": res })

                }
            )))
        .catch(error => Observable.of({ type: Affaire_Action.Affaire_on_Failure, payload: null }))
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying with the `this.userService.authenticateUser` ?
Seems like you are trying to call the function but the way you are doing is wrong.
What is the return type?!!! Observable or promise.

Suggestion: You should call services on you effect and dispatch actions from effect. You can also use `this.router.navigateByUrl("/home");` on your effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to navigate first which means it will redirect by that time i landed to home page the api call should be able to fill the state. by which am trying to use the load time.. like fire and forget ()on login ill call the api async and when the user goes the particular page by that time data will be loaded. inspite of going to that particular page and the loading the data.